# Issue with adding stock on Django website - Request reset or not hitting server

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm encountering an issue with my Django website where clients are unable to add stock after a certain period. Our team has tested the functionality successfully from our own computers, but when our client tests it from their side, the request seems to be reset or not hitting the server, even though it initially shows a 200 OK response. We suspect it might be related to antivirus software, as our client is only using the Windows Antivirus Defender. Have any of you experienced a similar issue or have any insights on what could be causing this behavior? Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

checked all neceessary debug

Comment: Can you please give more details, like the website you are hitting? is it web scribing or API hit? and what OS your client is using?